# My Facebook app can't be seen by users who do not have secure browsing enabled

Tags: php, facebook, ssl

I have created a simple FB app using PHP. To meet the new regulation imposed by FB, I have already installed SSL certificates on my server. However, the app can only be seen when secure browsing is enabled, else it will show only a blank canvas.

I know secure browsing is not enabled by default on FB. Is there any reason why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

You can forward users to use HTTPS when you see HTTP in the Request URI .

```
// forced HTTPS mechanism used in heroku Facebook App
if (substr(AppInfo::getUrl(), 0, 8) != 'https://' && $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != '127.0.0.1') {
    header('Location: https://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your login url make sure you gave url http:// not https://

```
     $loginUrl=$facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'scope'         => 'scopes',
    'redirect_uri'  =>'http://apps.facebook.com/YOURAPPNAMESPACE/'
      ));
```

Comment: hi Sandy thanks for the reply but i do not have these lines in my code

Comment: @user1397592 if you creating fb app and getting fb permission dialogue then you should have this code. If still you think not can you post ur code here?

Comment: My app does not have a permission dialogue, and that's why i don't see these lines.

Answer (score 0):

check in the application settings at developers page, you might have `HTTPS URL` setup in the `Canvas URL`